# Как обновить ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, update

В цикле создаю n-кнопок, и по нажатию на каждую кнопку должны добавляться данные в listView. Код работает, но сам UI не обновляется почему-то.

```
 List<Bludo> cash = new List<Bludo>();

      Button btn = new Button();
                        btn.Click += delegate
                        {

                            Bludo bl = new Bludo();
                            var data = btn.Tag.ToString().Split(';');

                            bl.tsena = Convert.ToDouble(data[0]);
                            bl.bludo = data[1];
                            cash.Add(bl);
                            listView.ItemsSource = cash;
                            listView.UpdateLayout();

                        };
```

Comment: А какого типа ваш `cash`? Если это не `ObservableCollection`, и не сработает.

Answer (score 5):

Вместо `List` используйте [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx), он наследуется от `INotifyCollectionChanged`, который в WPF перехватывается как изменение коллекции, но если Вам необходимо использовать именно `List`, то можете наследоваться от него и `INotifyCollectionChanged`, переопределив методы вставки/удаления